# Nuxt3 generate TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE')

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt3 + Vite + Leaflet + Bootstrap for my app. The app is working fine in development, but when I try to generate the static site using `npm run generate`, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isCE')
> and
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'namespaceURI')

I think it has to do with my plugins files.

Here are my config files for Nuxt3:

`plugins/nuxt.config.js`:

```js
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  target: 'static',
  css: [
      '~/assets/global.scss'
  ],
  router: {
      base: '/'
  }
})
```

`leaflet.client.js`:

```js
import L from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet.markercluster';
import 'leaflet-fullscreen';
import 'leaflet-sidebar';
import 'leaflet.vectorgrid';
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  return {
      provide: {
        L
      }
    }
})
```

`plugins/useBootStrap.client.ts`:

```js
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.provide('bootstrap', bootstrap)
  nuxtApp.provide('Tooltip', bootstrap)
  nuxtApp.provide('Carousel', bootstrap)
})
```

and my package.json:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free": "^2.13.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.1",
    "leaflet-fullscreen": "^1.0.2",
    "leaflet-sidebar": "^0.2.4",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",
    "leaflet.vectorgrid": "^1.3.0",
    "topojson-client": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-google-charts": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-gtag": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.11",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "vite": "^3.0.9",
    "vite-plugin-mkcert": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have formatted your question to be more readabale. Did you checked the github issues for each of your package with the given error? Looks like something heavily specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The problem is most probably coming from leaflet integration. How would you debug such a situation (except by removing some code and rebuild)?

Comment: That is indeed one solution. I hope that there are some community channel where you could get some help around that. Otherwise, trying to google that one around may be nice too: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20016

Answer (score 1):

I finally isolated the problem. The problem existed even with the most simple Nuxt app template so I looked for a server issue. And indeed, my apache server still had an old mod_pagespeed extension activated and it interfered with Nuxt hydration logic (by changing some files names).

Deactivating the extension solved my problem. Took me 3 days to realize!