# Using leaflet.markercluster with a Nuxt 3 app

Tags: leaflet, nuxtjs3, leaflet.markercluster

I'm using Leaflet with Nuxt3, TypeScript and Composition API on a production website.
As we're getting more and more markers, I'd like to use leaflet.markercluster but I can't get how to make it work properly

Here's my setup :

`leaflet.client.ts`

```js
import {
  LIcon,
  LMap,
  LMarker,
  LPopup,
  LTileLayer,
} from "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component("LMap", LMap);
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component("LTileLayer", LTileLayer);
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component("LMarker", LMarker);
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component("LIcon", LIcon);
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component("LPopup", LPopup);

  return {
    provide: {
      L,
    },
  };
});
```

`Map.vue`

```html
<client-only>
   <l-map 
       ref="locationsMap"
       :min-zoom="leafletOptions.minZoom"
       :max-zoom="leafletOptions.maxZoom"
       :zoom-animation="true"
       :zoom="leafletOptions.zoom"
       :center="leafletOptions.center"
       :useGlobalLeaflet="false"
       :options="{ tap: false }"
       @ready="onLeafletReady">
         <l-tile-layer :url="leafletOptions.url"/>
           <template v-for="location in locations"
                     :key="location.id">
             <l-marker
                :lat-lng="[location.attributes.lat, location.attributes.long]"
                v-if="location.attributes.active">
                  <div v-if="location.attributes.lat && location.attributes.long">
                    <l-popup class="text-center flex flex-col gap-y-4">
                     ...
                    </l-popup>
                    <l-icon>
                      ...
                    </l-icon>
                  </div>
              </l-marker>
            </template>
       </l-map>
        ...
</client-only>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {LIcon, LMap, LMarker, LPopup, LTileLayer} from "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

const leafletOptions = ref({
  url: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  minZoom: 5,
  maxZoom: 13,
  zoom: 5.5,
  map: null,
  center: [47.040182, 2.536054],
  bounds: null,
  overlayLocation: false,
  colors: ["#ED722E", "#F6BE00", "#979B0B", "#DA2C81"],
});

// Setup and api calls to get locations
</script>
```

`package.json`

```json
{
 ...,
 "depencencies": {
   "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.7.0",
   "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
   "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "nuxt": "^3.0.0",
   "typescript": "^4.9.4"
   "@types/leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.1",
 }
}
```

The thing is, now I try to group my markers by adding `leaflet.markercluster`. So I added something like this :

`leaflet.client.ts`

```js
...
import "leaflet.markercluster";
import "leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css";
import "leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  ...

  return {
    provide: {
      L,
    },
  };
});
```

But now I don't know what to do next. Using `L.markerClusterGroup()` as the official documentation says does not work as we get a 500 error for using a client-side method with ssr.

I also tried to directly import in my component with import :

`Map.vue`

```js
import { MarkerClusterGroup } from 'leaflet.markercluster';

const markersGroup = ref(null);

...

const onLeafletReady = async () => {
  markersGroup.value = new MarkerClusterGroup() // NOT WORKING
  await nextTick();
  leafletObject.value = locationsMap.value;
  leafletReady.value = true;

  leafletObject.value.addLayer(markersGroup.value)
}
```

But we got the same problem as using `L.anyMethod()` by getting a 500 error.

I saw that Sam85 on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885140/nuxt3-generate-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-isce/75063403#75063403) has the package installed, but that was not the same problem. :/

Has anyone ever tried to make it work with Nuxt 3 ?